# cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

Tags: python, django, docker

Полная ошибка выглядит так

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'mptt.templatetags.mptt_tags': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
```

насколько я понял, мне нужно исправить строчку `from django.db.models import FieldDoesNotExist` на `from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist` в файле **init.py**, у меня была похожая ошибка, я так сделал и вроде помогло, но проблема в том, что я не могу найти файл **init.py**, нигде, ни с помощью `Ctrl + O` в PyCharm, ни в самом ноутбуке, никак

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

#RUN pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \

RUN mkdir -p /Users/work/Projects/ims/api/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /Users/work/Projects/ims/api/requirements.txt

COPY . /Users/work/Projects/ims/api/requirements.txt
##RUN echo "$PWD"
RUN ls -al
#RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /opt/cron-ims/api/
COPY . .


RUN cd docs && make html

RUN chmod +x "./entrypoint.sh"
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
ENV PORT 80

CMD ["uwsgi", "./ims/uwsgi.ini"]
```

**docker-sompose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ims
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ims
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  api:
    build: api
    environment:
      - DATABASE_NAME=ims
      - DATABASE_USER=ims
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=ims
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - web-media:/opt/cron-ims/api/media/
      - web-staticfiles:/opt/cron-ims/api/staticfiles/
  www:
    build: www
    depends_on:
      - api
  pos:
    build: pos
    depends_on:
      - api

volumes:
  db-data:
  web-media:
  web-staticfiles:
```

**requirements.txt**

```
django==3.2.5
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
django-currentuser==0.5.3
django-debug-toolbar==2.0
django-filter==2.2.0
django-gtin-fields==0.1.2
django-mptt==0.10.0
djangorestframework==3.10.3
djoser==2.0.3
pillow==8.3.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
sentry-sdk==0.13.1
sphinx==2.2.1
uwsgi==2.0.18
```

Буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 0):

> Upgrade notes
> 0.12
>
> Add support for Django 3.1
> Drop support for Django 1.11.
> Drop support for Python 3.5.
> Fix an issue where the rebuild() method would not work correctly if you were using multiple databases.
> Update spanish translations.

У вас версия `0.10`, а `Django==3.2.5`

`mptt` просто пока не поддерживает вашу версию `django`. Ждите обновления,  либо ставьте `Django 3.1.X` и обновляйте `django-mptt`

[Источник](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade.html)

Comment: а что делать с `cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)` ?

Comment: ничего. я описал проблему. несовместимость версий. можете конечно пойти в django-mptt и поменять пути импорта, но это не лучший вариант, применять в крайних случаях, когда нет другого выхода.  Во временем добавят поддержку, так что лучше подождать